# Wild Card Before and After a String - MySql, PSQL

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, innodb, psql

I need to perform `Contains` operation in a column. For Contains operation we need use Wildcard before and after a word.

Ex: personalized

Query -> like '%sonal%'

As this type of query can't use indexes. Is there any way to increase the speed of the search.

Note: I use MySql(InnoDB) and PSQL

Answer (score 5):

PostgreSQL has solution - trigram index. Here is a [article](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/03/18/fast-search-using-postgresql-trigram-indexes/) or [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html)

```
postgres=# create extension pg_trgm ;
CREATE EXTENSION
postgres=# create index on obce using gin (nazev gin_trgm_ops);
CREATE INDEX
postgres=# explain select * from obce where nazev like '%Bene%';
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                  QUERY PLAN                                             │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ Bitmap Heap Scan on obce  (cost=20.00..24.02 rows=1 width=41)                           │
│   Recheck Cond: ((nazev)::text ~~ '%Bene%'::text)                                       │
│   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on obce_nazev_idx  (cost=0.00..20.00 rows=1 width=0)            │
│         Index Cond: ((nazev)::text ~~ '%Bene%'::text)                                   │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(4 rows)
```

It is working for regular expressions too.

Comment: Is gin index is better than b tree. Because im using B tree indexes. Will it be a problem when i change to gin index

Comment: GIN index is different than BTREE. These indexes are designed for different purposes. For this task, only GIN or GIST indexes will work.

Comment: Ok. I have more than 1M Records. For each insert and huge rows update it will take more time or not (When compared to B tree indexes). As it is creating every combination of our column value.

Comment: you can try GiST index - it should be faster than GIN for update. And yes, trigram index is expensive. `LIKE` operator is pretty bad for optimization.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL supports [FULLTEXT indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html).

You might be interested in my presentation [Full Text Search Throwdown](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql), in which I compare different fulltext indexing tools. The presentation is a bit old now, but some of it is still relevant.

---

Re your comments:

MySQL's fulltext indexing doesn't support partial word matches, although it supports a limited wildcard, but only at the end of patterns. And the InnoDB implementation of fulltext doesn't support it, only the MyISAM does. See mention of the `*` wildcard in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html

```
SELECT ... WHERE MATCH(mycolumn) AGAINST ('stack*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Elastic Search also support wildcards, but like MySQL, they aren't efficient if your wildcard is at the start of the pattern. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html

Sphinx Search supports an option for infix string indexing. If you set `min_infix_len` to a nonzero positive number, it will index all infix substrings as well as whole words.
See http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-min-infix-len

Comment: FullTextSearch Can be used only for words in a sentences. Ex: `hi hello world` in this `hello` can be searched but we can't search `worl` using this technique. Am i ryt?

Comment: Then what to do for my case ?

Answer (score 3):

I guess there is no logical optimization if you need to find any sequence of char at any position of the values.  If the current lookup takes several seconds then maybe you could benefit from using an external optimized index like this:

1. Add 2 extra columns: `offset` with an index and `length` without index.
2. Join all the values in a single text file and save on each row the offset and the length.
3. Write an external tool to do the search in the whole file (using something like `strstr()`) and return the offset.
4. Use the return offset to identify the row with something like `SELECT TOP 1 FROM table WHERE offset < @offset ORDER BY offset DESC`.
5. Use the `length` field to make sure the matched fragment does no lays between records: `@offset + @length` (the end of the searched string) is `<= offset + length` (the end of the value on the found row).

You could also keep the full joined text in a global variable or dedicated table inside the database, to avoid spawning an external process or accessing the disk.

Comment: Can you be more specific. With an example